# How to edit a function without rewrite its content?

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts but I cannot access to one of them. How I would edit the content of a function without rewriting it?

Example:

I know this can edit the function:

```
<script>
function a() {
alert('hi');
}
</script>
<script>
function a() {
alert('hi');
console.log('hi');
}
</script>
```

But I don't want to rewrite again the "alert('hi')".

Comment: Which text editor are you using to edit this function?

Comment: Are you wanting to add functionality to the function? That is, do you want to do whatever it already does plus something else?

Comment: Just *over* write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can steal the function's symbol, like this:

```
var b = a;             // <== Takes the original `a` and remembers it as `b`
a = function() {       // <== Assigns a new function to `a`
    var rv = b();      // <== Calls what used to be `a`, remembers its return value
    console.log("hi");
    return rv;         // <== Returns what the old function returned
};
```

Of course, if you don't need the return value thing, you can leave it out, but if you're pretending to be the old function, probably best to return what it returns.

If you need to pass along arguments to it and just want to pass *all* of the arguments your new function receives, you can do that with `Function#apply` and the special `arguments` pseudo-array:

```
var b = a;
a = function() {
    var rv = b.apply(this, arguments); // Calls the original `a` with the current 
                                       // `this` and all the args we were given
    console.log("hi");
    return rv;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set a new function to the old one, then reassign the old one:

```
function a() {
    alert('hi');
}
b = a;
a = function()
{
    b();
    console.log('hi');
}
a();
```

Note that you have to assign the new `a` using an expression: `a = function()...` If you just do `function a()...`, you get recursion and exceed the maximum call stack size.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to redefine the function source by search & replace:

```
eval(a.toString().replace(/(alert\(\'hi\'\)\;)/,"$1\nconsole.log('hi');"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the original function into a string, construct a new one and append the new line to it:

```
function a() {
     alert('a');
}

var b = new Function('(' + a + ")(); alert('b');")

b(); // would alert twice, 'a' & 'b'
```